# How to abstractly extend a path-dependent trait: "override trait"?

Tags: scala, overriding, traits, path-dependent-type

With a path-dependent trait, how do you specify, for a specific enclosing object, that this trait must support an additional feature? `override trait`? How do you refer to the original trait that the subtrait extends?

Specifically, I want to override the `Delta` trait in each `DeltaSet` object:

```
trait DeltaSet {
  type PertainsTo

  trait Delta {
    val pertainsTo: PertainsTo
  }
  . . .
}
```

In English, that’s “Every `Delta` in the same `DeltaSet` must pertain to the same kind of thing.”

A `DeltaSet` object should be able to add more attributes to the `Delta` trait, like `source` here:

```
val deltaSet = new DeltaSet {
  override type PertainsTo = UnorderedPair[TestNode]

  override trait Delta /* extends DeltaSet.Delta?? */ {  // <-- THE MYSTERY
    val source: TestNode
  }
  . . .
}
```

In English, that’s “Every `Delta` for `deltaSet` must also provide a source.”

So, `Delta` classes for use with that `DeltaSet` object must override the `source` attribute, like this:

```
case class MakeLinkDelta(fromNode: TestNode, toNode: TestNode)
  extends deltaSet.Delta
{
  override val pertainsTo = new UnorderedPair(fromNode, toNode)
  override val source = fromNode
  . . .
}
```

and similarly for `BreakLinkDelta` and other `Deltas` for `deltaSet`. (Each `Delta` for this `DeltaSet` describes a change to be made to a graph. Other `DeltaSet`s contain changes to completely different kinds of objects.)

I've tried a lot of variations, including `trait BaseDelta {...}; type DeltaT <: BaseDelta`, and so far none have compiled. How do you “say” in Scala, “For just this one `DeltaSet`, I want to require that every `Delta` provide a `source` attribute?”

Answer (score 2):

This works:

(1) Define a base `trait` in the enclosing trait, and make it the upper bound for an abstract `type`.

(2) Create the container object with an `object` statement, not a `val` statement.

(3) Put a class override on the `object`, defining the enclosed `trait` with the same name as the abstract `type`. This definition must extend the base `trait` and must *not* have the `override` keyword.

---

Here's (1), the enclosing trait:

```
trait DeltaSet {
  type PertainsTo

  trait BaseDelta {
    val pertainsTo: PertainsTo
  }

  type Delta <: BaseDelta          // <-- Since this is now a type, we can override it...
  . . .
}
```

Here’s (2), the `object` that defines a concrete `DeltaSet`, and (3), the class override that defines `Delta`:

```
object deltaSet extends DeltaSet {
  override type PertainsTo = UnorderedPair[TestNode]

  trait Delta extends BaseDelta {  // ...except we don't override, we just define a trait
    val source: TestNode           // with the same name as the abstract type.
  }
  . . .
}
```

I'm guessing that the reason `object` compiles and `val` fails is because a `val` doesn't define a namespace, and we need a namespace in order to refer to the enclosed, overridden `Delta` trait when we subclass it here:

```
case class MakeLinkDelta(fromNode: TestNode, toNode: TestNode)
  extends deltaSet.Delta           // Since deltaSet is a namespace, the dot syntax can refer
{                                  // to the Delta trait inside it.
  override val pertainsTo = new UnorderedPair(fromNode, toNode)
  override val source = fromNode
  . . .
}
```

(This last part is unchanged from the code in the question.)

Answer (score 0):

Extend `DeltaSet` and its `Delta` adding the `source` attribute:

```
trait DeltaSetTN extends DeltaSet {
  override type PertainsTo = UnorderedPair[TestNode]
  trait DeltaTN extends Delta {
    val source: TestNode
  }
}
```

Then:

```
class MakeLinkDelta(fromNode: TestNode, toNode: TestNode) extends DeltaSetTN {
  val delta = new DeltaTNImpl()
  class DeltaTNImpl extends DeltaTN {
    override val source = fromNode
    override val pertainsTo = new UnorderedPair[TestNode](fromNode, toNode)
  }
}
```

You may be interested in this [blog post](http://jonasboner.com/2008/10/06/real-world-scala-dependency-injection-di/) about dependency injection in Scala and the cake pattern.

Comment: Can you explain the relevant principle at work here? “You can’t override a path-dependent trait in an anonymous class”? “You can’t override a path-dependent trait, anywhere”? “Each path-dependent (`Delta`) object must extend the container (`DeltaSet`) trait”? I'm hoping that the last is not the true principle.

Comment: We can't override a trait. To do that, we extend and override its members. Not sure I understand your last point. A trait can't stay a trait when instantiated.

Comment: Thanks for "We can’t override a trait.” (Maybe that could go in the answer.) Clarifying the last point: in your solution, the `Delta` class extends the `DeltaSet` trait. That seems weird to me, like saying that a Cup is a kind of Cupboard. Is there some Scala principle that necessitates that?

Comment: I'll change `MakeLinkDelta` to `DeltaForLink` in the question, since “Make” might be causing confusion.

Comment: Sure re suggested changes. Can you clarify where in my code `Delta` extends `DeltaSet`?

Comment: `MakeLinkDelta extends DeltaSetTN`. I'm assuming (perhaps wrongly) that the intended meaning is (using the new name for the `Delta` class) `DeltaForLink extends DeltaSetForTestNodes`.

Comment: BTW, I just hit on a working solution that I'm reasonably happy with. It makes use of “you can’t override a trait”. I'll post it in another answer in a couple minutes. I don't fully understand the reasons for it, though, so I probably won't be accepting my own answer!

Comment: Look forward to it. :)

Comment: You can edit my answer, you know, with alternative names. I'll approve it. :)

Comment: Excellent. :) I think I'll switch back to `MakeLinkDelta` and mention a contrasting `BreakLinkDelta`. That should clarify that there can be many `Delta` classes for one `DeltaSet` (and require less editing all around).